# API embeded code is sending <style>, how do I ignore?

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed

I am using embeded JS code for a service I need included in my website. It is embedding its own `<style>` CSS along with the HTML elements. It is a new service and there is no support for sending anything else. How can I ignore the `<style>` so I can use my own CSS to integrate into the theme? I don't want to resort to using !important flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding `!important` to my CSS file since the JS file is loaded asynchronously and it would be more work to keep checking until it is loaded to remove the `<style>`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use same classes for your CSS and you include it after the JS code loads it **(assuming it loads it synchronously)** your classes will override the default settings.

The way the CSS is rendered - if there is a conflict between declaration the instructions passed "later" prevail.

```
<html>
  <head>
    YOUR JS HERE
    YOUR CSS to override your JS imported rules
  </head>
<html>
```

You need to make sure you understand how CSS assesses the "weight" of the instructions though (important, inline style, id, class, html tag)
https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ - here is a decent explanation how it works.

Comment: What if the JS is loaded in the <body>? I just have a snippet that is in <script> tags that loads the JS file from their server.

Comment: you can include `<style>` the same way. So you just need to use it later than your plugin is loaded. Your browser reads and renders HTML from the top to the bottom so order matters especially for CSS. 

Now, I don't guarantee it will work with your plugin, I didn't see it, but i suppose its worth trying.